# How can I add multiple spring batch jobs inside the scheduling configurer?

Tags: spring-batch, quartz-scheduler

So below sample java class configuration will get the CRON job expression from the database dynamically. So far it works only in 1 job. However, I have another job and tried adding it by invoking addTriggerTask method but job failed due to this error. Any recommendation how we can trigger multiple jobs?

```
   ERROR: required a single bean, but 2 were found
    
   Action: Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class DynamicScheduler implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DynamicScheduler.class);

    @Autowired
    ConfigRepo repo;

    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private Job job;


    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {

        taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(() -> executeJob("job1"), t -> {
            CronTrigger crontrigger = new CronTrigger(repo.findById("cronExpressionJob1").get().getConfigValue());

            return crontrigger.nextExecutionTime(t);
        });

    }

    public void executeJob(String jobName) {        

        try {

            JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                    .addString(jobName, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())).toJobParameters();

            jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Failed due to exception thrown.", e);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current code, you are using `@Autowired` to inject a `Job` into `DynamicScheduler`.  This is unambiguous when you only have a single job, but as soon *as you add another job Spring cannot disambiguate which job you want injected*.

That's why you are seeing the error:

> ERROR: required a single bean, but 2 were found
>
> Action: Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to
> identify the bean that should be consumed

If you want to handle multiple jobs, then I suggest removing `@Autowired private Job job;` from your class and use a [JobRegistry](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/JobRegistry.html) to look up your `Job` by name as a local variable.  Then pass that `Job` along with its `JobParameters` to `jobLauncher.run()`.

```java
// get JobParameters for jobName
Job job = jobRegistry.getJob( jobName );
jobLauncher.run( job, jobParameters );
```